# is there a built-in hash implementation in java?

Tags: java, hash

I have an array of 6 ints that I am interested in getting a hash value for (an int).
I am wondering if there is a relatively strong and fast hash function for this case which is implemented in Java.

I am almost tempted to convert the 6 ints to a String (as if each int is a unicode character or something like that, not by representing each int as an actual number) and use "hashcode", but it sounds very inefficient to me, I think want something faster. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all java defined objects have hashcode already implemented, even for arrays.

Comment: Erm, are you sure you understand what a hashing function does? Or do you mean you're trying to get a hash that represents that particular *sequence* of ints?

Comment: exactly, a hash for a sequence of 6 ints.

Comment: What do you want to do with the hash value? Are you saving it in a map or using it for something else, like an id?

Comment: I agree with Brian, the question just doesn't make sense.  what properties do you want this hash code to have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int[] myIntArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int myHashCode = Arrays.hashCode(myIntArray);
```

Note: Arrays has `hashCode()` implemented for arrays of all primitive types, not just ints.

Also, something tells me you're going to use a sequence of 6 numbers as a passcode, and its hash to match it against.  In this case, you're going to want a really, really long hash.  Something at least 24 bytes long, instead of the 4 that an int will give you.  (having a larger hash space than your input space will reduce collisions.)

I'd go for SHA-384 or higher.  And don't forget to salt.

Comment: btw, just as a side note, if your hash space is larger than your input space, there is no point in using a hash function, you might as well use your input space to be the "hash space".

Comment: @kloop I was expecting you were going to use it as a security measure.  Otherwise, you're right, it's not very useful to hash something to a larger space than the input space.